# Pass each product subtotal to database with controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to pass each value product subtotal to database with controller. Right now, the subtotal will store to database if there's only one product in cart, but if there's two or more, the subtotal won't store and it shows the error that the subtotal is null. I'm thinking that I should pass the subtotal with array because each subtotal has its own product, but I don't know how. Here is the code.

**Blade and JS**

```
<table class="table" id="cart_checkout">
                        <thead class="bg-transparent">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Thumbnail</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Brand</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Product</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Size</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Price</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach($cartlists as $cartlist)
                        <tbody class="bg-transparent" class="checkout_cart">
                            <tr class="cartpage">
                                <td class="text-center"><img src="{{asset('../storage/images/Products/' . $cartlist->product->productimage)}}" width="150px;" height="150px;" alt="Image"></td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->brand->name}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->productname}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->productsize}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">Rp. <span class="price">{{ $cartlist->product->productprice}}</span></td>
                                <td class="cart-product-quantity text-center" width="132px">
                                    <div class="input-group quantity">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend decrement-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1">
                                        <div class="input-group-append increment-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">+</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span class="subtotal">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</span>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
```

```
function priceTotal() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $('#cart_checkout > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            var qty = $(this).find('.qty-input').val()
            var price = parseInt($(this).find('.price').text());
            var subTotal = qty * price;
            grandTotal += subTotal;
            $(this).find('.subtotal').text('Rp. ' + subTotal.toLocaleString('en'));

            var sub_total = $('.subtotal').html();
            $("#subtotal").val(sub_total);
        });
        $('.grandtotal').text('Rp. ' + grandTotal.toLocaleString('en'));

        var grand_total = $('.grandtotal').html();
        $("#grandtotal").val(grand_total);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
        $cartlists = Cart::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        //get all product from cart
        $products = [];
        foreach ($cartlists as $cartlist) {
            $product = Product::where('id', '=', $cartlist->product_id)->first();
            $products[] = $product;
        }


        $carts = Cart::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        if ($carts->count() > 0) {

            $order = new Order();
            $order->order_number = 'ORD-' . strtoupper(mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999));
            $order->status = 'pending';
            $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $order->grand_total = $request->grandtotal;
            $order->save();

            foreach ($carts as $cart) {
                $order_product = new order_product();
                $order_product->order_id = $order->id;
                $order_product->product_id = $cart->product_id;
                $order_product->is_review = 'no';
                $order_product->subtotal = $request->subtotal;
                $order_product->save();
            }

            //get all shipment
            $shipments = Shipment::all();

            //get all user address
            $addresses = Address_Delivery_Users::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

            $detailaddresses = null;

            return view('/transactions/delivery', compact('order', 'addresses', 'detailaddresses', 'shipments', 'products'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('status', 'There is no product on your cart, pick some!');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are getting subtotal from the request when you have price and qty in each row. just multiply price * qty when entering subtotal in DB.